# A hot metal block in the cool sea

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

(I just want to double check that my answer is correct.)

> A metal block at the boiling temperature of water is submerged in the sea where the water temperature is $20$°C. If after $15$ minutes the temperature of the block falls to $68$°C, how long will its temperature stay at between $60.5$ and $59.5$°C?

Using the formula
$$T=T_a+(T_0-T_a)e^{-kt}$$
where $T_a$ is the ambient temperature, $T_0$ is the initial temperature of the object and $T$ is its temperature at a given time $t$, I got $20$ minutes. Is that correct?

Comment: The block took $15$ minutes to fall $32$ degrees, and you think it will take $20$ minutes to fall a single degree? Does that sound right to you? Even knowing it goes slower at lower temperatures, that's a bold statement.

Comment: @Arthur: If the temperature were just over $21^\circ C$ it might be true, but it is not

Comment: Out of curiosity, what $k$ did you find?

Comment: Vincent,.I got k= 0.034

Comment: Arthur, check the unedited post. Someone edited my post which have changed the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

So in your case:

$$T_0 = 100 ~~~~~ T_a = 20 ~~~~~ t = 15 ~~~~~ T = 68$$

You have to find $k$ first of all.

$$e^{-kt} = \frac{T - T_a}{T_0 - T_a} =\frac{68 - 20}{100 - 20} = \frac{48}{80} = 0.6$$

Now

$$\ln(e^{-kt}) = \ln(0.6) ~~~~~ \to ~~~~~ -kt = \ln(0.6)$$

Hence

$$k = -\frac{\ln(0.6)}{15} = 0.034055041584399$$

Can you proceed now?

Maybe you calculated a wrong $k$?

Comment: That's the value of k I calculated. The equation then became T=20+80e^(-0.034t) then I substituted 60°C at T to get the value of t. I got t=20 mins.

Comment: @AgentCollins But that calculation tells you how long it takes to reach $60$ from $100$. Not how long it takes to reach $59.5$ from $60.5$.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you sir. I got 0.74 mins

Comment: Definitely meaningful :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the formula *twice*. Once using the initial given data about $68$ degrees and $15$ minutes to calculate $k$, and then once more to find the time the block took to cool down from $60.5$ to $59.5$ degrees. The second time you need to change both $T_0$ and $T$ in order to get the answer you're actually after.